# How do I make the Posts comments available in my homepage and user/show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, relationships

Here is my homeController:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def home
        if logged_in?
            @post  = current_user.posts.build
            @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
    end

    def about
    end

    def privacy
    end

    def terms
    end
end
```

Here is my Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
        end
    end
```

My posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = "Post created!"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            @feed_items = []
            render 'home/home'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_post
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

       # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
       def post_params
           params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :picture)
       end
   end
```

My user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments
    has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy

    has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
.............................................
.............................................
end
```

My post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum:40 }   
end
```

How do I make sure both the posts and their comments can be accessed in the home page( homeController corresponding to the home view) and the user#show ? I was able to access and view the posts in homeview and the user#show but I am having trouble with accessing the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way.

UserController#index

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

in show html

```
render @posts
```

In order to render the posts correctly you will have to have a _post.html.erb so that rails knows how to render them.

Comment: Thanks Austio ! What about the comments ?

Comment: Same thing only doing it with @comment equal to Comment.all

Comment: Once you get this working, commit and try to implement using form objects.  It against best practice to have too many instance variables in the controller.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects

Comment: Thanks Austio. What about having a comment form in the home page that helps create comment. I tried but I am getting the following error :

Comment: Hey @MoussaSarr probably best to create a new stackoverflow issue on the question you just mentioned.  It is a little different and may help someone else out in the future.  Once you do that and provide all you are having trouble implementing yourself and i'll provide guidance when i get the opportunity.